# Rails Includes - Association named 'albums' was not found on Song; perhaps you misspelled it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following Schema

```
create_table "songs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",       null: false
    t.text     "lyrics",      null: false
    t.string   "youtube_url"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "album_id"
    t.integer  "artist_id"
  end
```

When i try to do the following

```
  def index
    @songs ||= find_songs
  end

private
def find_songs
    songs = Song.includes(:albums).order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    songs = songs.order(:title) if params['sort_by'] == "title"
    songs
  end
```

I get the following error

> Association named 'albums' was not found on Song; perhaps you
>   misspelled it?

Comment: What are your associations between song and album?

Comment: Did you declare the relationship with albums in Song model?

Comment: what is  your Models associations ?

Comment: @z.shan Polymorphic )

Comment: can you share model code , i want to see how you define associations?

Comment: @z.shan right here he has `ROUTES` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417612/rails-redirect-to-an-anchor-tag-from-the-controller/36418127#36418127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you have an association as `Album has_many songs` and `Song belongs_to album`.

`includes` should take the association name.

```
songs = Song.includes(:album).order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```